If $A$ and $B$ are different matrices satisfying $A^3=B^3$ and $A^2B=B^2A$ then
If $A$ and $B$ are different matrices satisfying $A^3=B^3$ and $A^2B=B^2A$ then
(a) $\det(A^2+B^2)=0$
(b) $\det(A-B)=0$
(C) both $\det(A^2+B^2$ and $\det(A-B)$ are zero
(d) Atleast one of both is zero
My Solution:
Let $P=(A^2+B^2)(A-B)$
$P=(A^3-A^2B+B^2A-B^3)\implies P=O$
Hence $(A^2+B^2)(A-B)=O$
There are three possibility here
Case $1$: $\det(A^2+B^2)\neq0$ and $\det(A-B)=0$ then we can multiply by inverse of $(A^2+B^2)$ on both side to obtain $A-B=O$ hence $A=B$ but this is not true because we are given that $A$ and $B$ are two different matrices
Case $2$:  $\det(A^2+B^2)=0$ and $\det(A-B)\neq 0$ then we can multiply by inverse of $(A-B)$ on both side to obtain $A^2+B^2=O$
Case $3$: $\det(A^2+B^2)=0$ and $\det(A-B) = 0$ then What should we say about Matrices??
My Doubt is about Case $3$ also Given answer is option $D$
Sane Question has been asked here $A$ and $B$ are different matrices satisfying $A^3=B^3$ and $A^2B=B^2A$ but I does not clear my doubt

From the argument in case 1, we know that $\det(A^2+B^2) = 0$, or else we are forced to conclude $A=B$. However, both $\det(A-B)=0$ and $\det(A-B) \ne 0$ are possible:

We satisfy all conditions if $A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 2\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, because $A^2=B^2=0$, so $A^3=B^3=0$ and $A^2B = B^2A=0$. Here, $\det(A-B) = 0$.
We also satisfy all conditions if $A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, for the same reason. Here, $\det(A-B) = 1$.

I would argue that this makes (a) the correct answer, since it is more precise than (d), but technically the statements in (a) and (d) are both true.
